# What is the right way to create key => values array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this PHP array:

```
$teams = array(
    "img1" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "img2" => "img/img2.jpg",
    "img3" => "img/img3.jpg",
    ...
);
```

Is there any way to get the same array in Javascript? By same array I mean a array with `key => values`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no associate arrays in javascript, but you can use objects with a key.value pair.

```
var obj = {};
obj.myNewKey = myNewValue;
```

You can also refer to these object properties in the following way:

```
obj['myNewKey'] = myNewValue;
```

Just keep in mind that although it looks like an associative array, it is actually an object.

There is also this way:

```
var obj = {
  myNewKey:"myNewValue",
  "myOtherKey":"myOtherValue"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `echo "var teams = ".json_encode($teams);`

Answer (score 0):

No. Arrays are indexed numerically.

However, objects allow string keys to values, similar to an associative array (but not quite - it is unordered and has none of the Array methods).

```
var teams = {
    "img1":"img/img1.jpg",
    "img2":"img/img2.jpg",
    "img3":"img/img3.jpg"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a={"key":"value","key2":"value2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to have the exact array from your php transfered to your script tag in html you could pass it as a json string in the following way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
         // some js code here
         var teams = <?php echo json_encode($teams); ?>;
         // some other js code
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        page html content here
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan, to evaluate the json string and convert it to an JS object, or is there a better way to make ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php se my suggestion. No need to do anything except put a `var varname =` in front of it

Comment: Okay, I got it now, thanks, I've edited my answer, if you don't mind, please remove the downvote